# Coproduct decomposition of the quot scheme functor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, schemes

I am reading FGA explained and stuck on this argument:
The functor $\mathfrak{Q}uot_{E/X/S}$ naturally decomposes as a co-product

$$\mathfrak{Q}uot_{E/X/S}=\coprod_{\Phi\in \mathbb{Q}[\lambda]} \mathfrak{Q}uot_{E/X/S}^{\Phi,L}$$

([Here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0504590.pdf) is Nitsure's article where you can find the definition of quot scheme)

I am familiar with the definition of coproduct of objects in a category, but confused about how is coproduct defined for functors. I would also like to know why the above statement is true.

Thanks!

Comment: @Hoot  But how can one see the decomposition? I am worried about the fact that the Hilbert polynomial is only locally constant. If one <F,q> happens to have distinct $\Phi$ on different fibres, would it cause problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "naive" coproduct of functors where you define $(\coprod_i F_i)(T)=\coprod_i F_i(T)$ in not a sheaf in general. If you sheafify, (at least in the case you're interested in) you should get a description like this: an element of $(\overline{\coprod_i F_i})(T)$ (the sheafification) is a decomposition $T_i$ of $T$ as a disjoint union $T=\coprod_i T_i$ (same indices) plus a family of elements $\xi_i\in F_i(T_i)$.

Since the Quot scheme is a sheaf, you should interpret that coproduct as the "sheaf coproduct". In this case, the decomposition as a disjoint union corresponds to the fact that the Hilbert polynomial is locally constant.

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but it seems in our case the functors $\mathfrak{Q}out_{*}^{**}$ are all functors from the category of schemes to category of sets. Why would one need the coproduct to be a sheaf?

Comment: It's not dumb :) When you define the Quot functor, you're hoping that it's going to end up begin representable, i.e. there will be a Quot scheme with a universal quotient sheaf on it, etc.
Now every representable functor is a sheaf (for the fpqc topology, or any coarser one, see for example http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0412512 ), so if you hope that the functor you're defining is representable, it should be a sheaf, at the very least.

Comment: I guess that doesn't precisely answer your question. The point is that when you write $Quot_{E/X/S}$ as a coproduct, since you know it is a sheaf, you're going to have to use the "sheaf coproduct", because the naive coproduct as presheaves is not a sheaf.

Comment: You're welcome!